# http auth rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

What's wrong with this picture: I want to add more than one login to my app - really simple http auth...this is working locally but only lets me log in as user1/pass1 once I've uploaded it to Heroku...If I try user2/pass2 it wont let me log in.

Any ideas?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery

  USER_NAME, PASSWORD = "user1", "pass1"
  USER_NAME2, PASSWORD2 = "user2", "pass2"
  before_filter :authenticate

private

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
    (user_name == USER_NAME && password == PASSWORD) || (user_name == USER_NAME2 && password == PASSWORD2) 
  end
 end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with the same code that you have. I made a [heroku app](http://test-hardy-app.heroku.com/) and made same constants like you have made. But did't face any problem for using either of the password. Can you provide more detail about you app ?